# How to give permission to an IAM group in S3 Bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I want to be able to specify an iam group as the principal within my policy but i have been reading that you cannot specify an iam group as part of a resource based policy. I could potentially add in a list of iam users but then my policy would look really messy. What is the best approach to take if i cannot add an iam group arn as the principal within my policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot specify an IAM group as the principal in a resource-based policy, you have a few options:

1. Attach the policy directly to the IAM users: In this case, you would
   need to specify each IAM user ARN in the policy. This approach can
   quickly become messy and difficult to manage as the number of IAM
   users grows.
2. Use an IAM role: An IAM role is a way to grant permissions to AWS
   services or applications that run on AWS. You can create an IAM role
   that can be assumed by IAM users or IAM groups. You can then specify
   the IAM role in the policy instead of the IAM users or IAM groups.
   This approach provides a cleaner and more scalable way to manage
   permissions.
3. Use a service control policy (SCP): An SCP is a type of policy that
   is used to set permissions boundaries for an AWS account. You can
   use an SCP to allow or deny access to AWS services for IAM groups,
   IAM users, or IAM roles. This allows you to manage permissions for
   multiple users in a centralized and organized manner.

I would recommend option 2 or 3 as the best approach, as they provide a cleaner and more scalable way to manage permissions compared to specifying individual IAM user ARNs in the policy.

Comment: Note that SCP and permissions boundaries are two different, but closely related, things. An SCP is applied to all IAM principals in an AWS account, while permissions boundaries are associated with specific IAM users or roles within an AWS account.

Comment: I currently have IAM Groups and IAM users inside these groups. Are you saying that I should create an IAM role and attach that to the principal section in my policy instead ? This policy is a bucket policy so it will be applied across several buckets.

Will the IAM role created have the same policy as I have for my S3 Buckets ?

Comment: Your #1 option seems a little mis-stated. If you're proposing that the IAM users are all given the relevant S3 permission by attaching a policy to each user then user ARNs aren't part of it. If you're proposing to add all the IAM user ARNs to the S3 bucket policy then user ARNs *are* part of it but policies don't need to be attached to the IAM users.

Comment: I am essentially adding all the IAM user ARNs to the S3 bucket policy since I cannot add in the IAM group arn. The bucket policy is pretty much saying allow "s3:GetObject" and s3:ListBucket" on these resources (name of buckets) if the principals of type AWS are  identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::<aws_account_id>:user/testuser@gmail.com"]

Comment: Are you saying that whatever permissions I specify in the bucket policy , them permissions are attached to the iam user ?

Comment: If an IAM user is in the same AWS account that owns the S3 bucket then you can grant bucket access to that IAM user in the S3 bucket policy or with policies attached to the IAM user (or group that the IAM user is in). You don't need both.